# Outputting a random record from csv?

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that contains 6 columns. I want to return one record (not the whole row) at random into my web page. For example, from row 5 return column 1 and 4.

The code below returns the whole file (columns 1, 2, 3). I only want one row returned. How do I modify this code to bring back one record?

```
<?PHP
$csvfile = "table.csv";
$file_handle = fopen($csvfile, "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";
    }
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code above this is how you could potentially modify it to show a particular row and column. As @Dagon mentioned in his post you could use array_rand for random entries (see below). You could also specify the row and column positions in an array if you like.

```
<?php

$csvfile = "table.csv";
$file_handle = fopen($csvfile, "r");
$line_of_text = array();

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);

// Random Row and Column
$random_row = array_rand($line_of_text);
$random_column =  array_rand($line_of_text[$random_row]);
echo $line_of_text[$random_row][$random_column];

//Specified Row 5 Column 1
$row = 5;
$column = 1;
echo $line_of_text[$row-1][$column-1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

inefficient, however you could change print to

```
$p[]= ...
```

then after the loop

```
echo $p[array_rand($p)];
```

Comment: thanks. agreed not most efficient method. is there a way of pulling a record without the loop?